# Certificate error during Jenkins plugin update

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Since a few months I have problems updating Jenkins plugins.

As soon as I want to update more than one or two plugins at a time I get the following message for all other plugins:

[sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvOqE.png)

However, if I then update each of these plugins individually and restart the Jenkins server in between, it works.

About my System:

- Jenkins 2.321
- OpenJDK 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to update the JRE:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67756

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).